# How do i embed Payment processing and shopping cart in my python appengine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, shopping-cart, payment-processing

I have looked everywhere for information on how to create a web store in my python app. Can I use google wallet? They seem to have API's for all other languages but python. Is there an API that works with appengine? Does anyone have a link to any tutorials that explain how to embed payment processing in appengine? Is there a good shopping cart API I can use with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django CMS https://www.django-cms.org/en/e-commerce/ uses Python and App Engine has Django support that you can read about here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

Comment: Also, here is an open source project using Python and App Engine for a webstore https://github.com/prakhar1989/JokaStore

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The open source project seemed to be what I was looking for, I was hoping more for something solid on that platform: Appengine-python-jinja2. Django CMS seems to use mysql and cloud-sql, where I really liked the Datastore.